# Problema ao converter datas no PHP

Tags: php

Tenho que comparar datas para fazer várias funções no site, o que pega a hora atual é essa instrução:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
$hora = date("d/m/Y H:i");
```

Que retorna `01/07/2017 18:28`. Tenho a instrução que faz a leitura do banco de dados e converte:

```
$sel_hora_carrossel = $r_sql_car_1[0];
$sel_hora_carrossel_converte = date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($sel_hora_carrossel));
```

Que retorna `07/01/2017 18:11` e não sei porque e nem onde mais procurar, porque as datas não batem, apesar de ambas usarem o `date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");`.

Comment: o que exatamente quer dizer, em linguagem de programação, não batem?

Comment: Os retornos não batem. um retorna "01/07/2017" e outro retorna "07/01/2017".

Comment: Para confirmar, qual o valor de `$sel_hora_carrossel`? É `01/07/2017`?

Comment: Parece-me que a data está sendo gravada no banco de dados no formato `mm/dd/YY` e como 1 é um mês válido, ele permite você fazer a formatação como `dd/mm/YY` sem dar erro, mas gerando um resultado inesperado. Tem como confirmar como está salvo no banco de dados e qual é a consulta feita para obter esse valor?

Comment: Um cuidado a ser tomado é com input type="date". Apesar de se digitar no campo o formato dd/mm/aaaa essa data será salva no banco no formato aaaa-mm-dd ....